# OK we're all nerds here, so really, how on earth should I use a Japanese toilet?

Tags: japan, tips-and-tricks, local-customs, hygiene

OK so for anyone who's traveled to Japan you know what I'm talking about.

They're devices that are a textbook example of excessive featuritis.

But I want to use something other than the flush knob before leaving Japan. What is a feature that has the following characteristics:

- Common to most Japanese toilets.
- Hard to get wrong - won't create a mess or damage the toilet.
- Simple to comprehend - more likely to involve romaji or kana or simple kanji or pictures.

[image]

Comment: I'm almost sure I'll regret this, but can you include a picture of how a Japanese toilet looks like?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilets_in_Japan

Comment: added a picture of one with 'featuritis' - let me know if that's what you mean, or if you mean the type like on http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~ad8y-hys/movie.htm

Comment: @mark the link isn't broken, but I don't see any non text content on my iPhone.

Comment: @MarkMayo: the one with featuritis, not the one on the asahi-net web page.

Comment: Good good, I guessed right then ;)

Comment: http://www.engrish.com/2016/09/i-was-trying-to-forget-about-the-camp/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Wikivoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Japan#Toilets) tells you all you need to know -- and I'm going to quote most of it, since I originally wrote the entry!

> Don't panic — help is at hand. The first key to solving the puzzle is
>   that the actual flush mechanism is usually not operated by the control
>   panel: instead, there is a standard, familiar, Western-style lever,
>   switch or knob somewhere and it is thus entirely possible to take care
>   of your business without ever using the washlet features. (In rare
>   cases, mostly with very high-end gear, flushing is integrated; if
>   lifting your bottom off the seat doesn't do the trick, look for
>   buttons labeled 大 or 小, meaning a big or small flush respectively, on
>   a wireless control panel on the wall.) The second key to exploration
>   is that there is always a big red button labeled 止 on the panel —
>   pressing this will instantly stop everything. Older models simply have
>   a lever nearby that controls the flow of a sprayer.
>
> Armed with this knowledge you can now begin to dig deeper. Typical
>   controls include the following:
>
> Oshiri (おしり) - "buttocks", for spraying your rear - typically shown in blue with a stylized butt icon; this action can be unnerving,
>   but travellers should not be afraid - by the second or third attempt
>   it will seem normal
>
> Bidet (ビデ) - for spraying your front - typically shown in pink with a female icon
>
> Kansō (乾燥) - "dry", for drying off when finished - typically yellow with a wavy air icon

[image]

> Other, smaller buttons can be used to adjust the exact pressure,
>   angle, location and pulsation of the jet of water. Sometimes the seat
>   of the toilet is heated, and this can be also regulated. One
>   explanation is that since houses are not usually centrally heated, the
>   toilet business can be made a little more convenient by heating the
>   seat. To be polite and save energy, you should leave the cover down on
>   heated toilet seats.

And if that wasn't enough, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilets_in_Japan) tells you *way, way* more than you need to know.

Comment: D'oh! I didn't think googling would help me. It's not perfect for criteria 2, but maybe nothing would fit all three.

Comment: I don't think you can possibly damage the toilet, no matter what you do to the control panel.  And neither will any of those create a mess as long as you're actually sitting on the thing -- just resist the temptation to stand next to it and play with the controls!

Comment: What's the difference between the two buttock spraying options? One icon seems to suggest the water stream split in two and each cleans one the centre of one buttock, while the other icon suggests an even shower of water droplets showering the entire posterior. Both of which seem a bit odd... `\-:`

Comment: The second one is *yawaraka*, "soft", presumably meaning a dainty, misty spray instead of a firehose blast up your pooper.  I can't recall ever seeing that one in real life though, the control panel above is definitely more towards the Space Shuttle end of the spectrum.

Comment: You did explained the buttons, but not the procedure.

Comment: Rumour has it that one of those buttons is the ejector seat!

Answer (score 27):

1. Sit on the toilet
2. Press the buttons (with great aplomb)
3. Enjoy a whole new spectrum of toilet-based sensation

It worked for me!

Answer (score 15):

Ignore it.  Ignore it all.  Treat it as decoration.  The all important flush lever is on a separate system.  You can usually find it on the side of the cistern.

Some toilets have a lever that you can move in two ways.  These are marked with two symbols: 大 and 小.  You see how the first symbol (大) looks like a man standing with his arms outstretched, as if to say, “It was **this** long!”  That symbol mean big flush.  The other symbol means small flush.  That’s all there is to it.

Comment: There's also a mnemonic for the `小` symbol too. It's a knife cutting something into two **small** -er pieces.

Comment: A fine mnemonic, but I'm already using it to remember the kanji for half (半).

Comment: @hippietrail In 2018, a "poop knife" confession was posted on Reddit. It became a meme (for those that are curious, it's easy to find by Googling). Being familiar with and reminded of that story, this mnemonic was rather confusing. I needed to read it multiple times to understand why it fit the small flush. (Though your comment predates the meme by almost 6 years.)