# OK we are all adults here, so really, how on earth should I live without bidet?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, local-customs, hygiene

This is the part four in the interesting series: "OK we are all X here, so really". You can find the past episodes here:

1. [OK we're all adults here, so really, how on earth should I use a squat toilet?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3080/ok-were-all-adults-here-so-really-how-on-earth-should-i-use-a-squat-toilet?rq=1)
2. [OK we're all nerds here, so really, how on earth should I use a Japanese toilet?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5599/ok-were-all-nerds-here-so-really-how-on-earth-should-i-use-a-japanese-toilet)
3. [How on earth can I use a Canadian toilet without splashing myself?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8944/how-on-earth-can-i-use-a-canadian-toilet-without-splashing-myself)

Travelling always requires a bit of adjustment. While doing our favorite activity we always leave home our comfort, our routines and, unfortunately, Italians (and others) leave home their beloved [bidet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidet).

The question is simple: what are the substitutes / tips&tricks for bidet while travelling in bidet-unfriendly countries so that we can do our business without end up feeling, let's say, uncomfortable?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I never used a bidet, but in my travels I always have a pack of wet tissues with me. There is a lot of choice around - from individually packed to large, 50+ pieces packs, antibacterial, scented, for make-up removal, etc. You can choose between hand wipes, facial wipes or even baby wipes.

There are a couple of good things about them. First of all, they are versatile - you can use them as a bidet substitute but also to cleanse your hands before/after food, to refresh your face and in general, to clean your skin if it gets dirty. They are much lighter than a bottle of water so can be easily carried around in a pocket or a small bag. In places where water is scarce it seems like a waste to have a dedicated water for the 'bidet business'. Wet wipes are also easy to share between fellow travellers. And finally, if you are travelling by plane only with the hand luggage, you can take your wet wipes on board (at least according to what [Heathrow airport guide indicates](http://www.heathrowairport.com/heathrow-airport-guide/heathrow-security/faqs#wetwipes).)

Comment: There are also a couple of bad things about them. [1](http://uk.businessinsider.com/nycs-sewers-have-a-flushable-wipe-problem-2015-3), [2](http://thinkprogress.org/climate/2015/03/23/3637422/poop-beach/).

Answer (score 7):

In many parts of the world bidet is a must in toilets. Bidet absence indeed will not make you feel comfortable specially if you are used to it like in Italy and other parts of the world such as Asia.

There is a solution, it is not as good as bidet but will do the job. Always keep a water bottle with you and use it as you wish, whether rinsing the genitals and then wipe it with paper or wet some tissues then wipe with it. The large water bottle (1.5L) is usually enough to do the job.

If you are in a country that do not use bidet always keep an empty bottle in your backpack and fill it before going to toilet.

Comment: +1 I heard the water bottle trick from backpackers in order to avoid having to carry toilet paper and polluting the backcountry while on extended hikes.

Comment: And be careful not to confuse it with your other water bottle.

Answer (score 7):

After seeing [MeNoTalk's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/27376/6083), I realized that I should have Googled for "portable bidet spray", et voilà

[image]
[Washmate Portable Bidet in a Bottle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001BYV3J6)

Which is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Very smart idea!

Answer (score 6):

I myself from a country that uses a bidet or a bidet spray, and I know what you are talking about. For me, in short term travels where I travel light (which I do every week) I just use a water bottle and make a hole at the top, squeeze it and i got my spray-like cleaning. In long term travels, you can always carry this with you:

[image]

It is basically a portable bidet spray, found easily in the middle east for travelers, it can fit almost any tap and will just do the job.

Comment: Oh, the portable hose seems okay. The problem is that it wouldn't work in those stall toilets where there's no water tap. Hole-in-the-cap thing sounds very practical, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you just have to bite the bullet and ..ahem... get the 'business' done as soon as possible.  I have travelled in some places that use the dreaded 'squatties' (squat toilets).  Some practicalities:

1. Try not to make contact with any surfaces.
2. Carry some disinfectant hand wash with you.
3. *always* carry spare toilet paper!

Just think of it as something that has to be done, done quickly and as cleanly as possible.

Comment: -1 but that is the point, the op wants to do it as quickly and cleanly as possible, but misses a vital ingredient, a bidet

Comment: True, my reply was an attempt to give serious advice to avoid being caught out while travelling.