# How can I wash myself Indian-style (using water not toilet paper) in Western toilets?

Tags: usa, europe, hygiene, western-europe

As an Indian I have grown up in Delhi using water to wash after using the toilet instead of toilet paper. In Indian culture this is considered a cleaner practice because of the use of water in order to wash the privates instead of toilet paper which may leave a residue.

Although I was able to comfortably adjust with the toilet paper system, many Indian people find it quite difficult and "dirty".

Are there any tips for a traveler to appropriately conduct themselves while fulfilling their wish of using water instead of toilet paper. I have heard of several people carrying PET bottles to the washroom in Western countries due to lack to tap and jug or hand shower, but I feel this is even worse and inappropriate as well.

Comment: >Although I was able to comfortably adjust with the toilet paper system, many Indian people find it quite difficult and "dirty". What source you got on this ?

Comment: >I have heard of several people carrying PET bottles to the washroom in Western countries due to lack to tap and jug or hand shower, but I feel this is even worse and inappropriate as well. - This is perfectly alright IMO. I have given away empty soda bottles to many of my Indian colleagues in the US. Even if I see someone take a bottle of water into a public restroom, I have never found it to be inappropriate.

Comment: @happybuddha Many older people in my family find it difficult and do not like the idea of using toilet paper and encourage me to only use the toilet when I can take a shower afterwards or carry a bottle etc. I personally think that it is difficult to use a bottle as you may not have one or may have to buy a drink just for the bottle and dispose the drink. Some people also tend to use dedicated bottles which I feel is inappropriate and unhealthy

Comment: Does this post answer your question? http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/17641/324

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it will be better than just dry toilet paper.  [Wet wipes](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=wet%20wipes&sprefix=wet+wi%2Caps&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Awet%20wipes) are sold in most grocery/sundries stores in the baby section.  They can even be purchased in small packages which are made to fit in a purse and some of them are specifically sold as being flushable (i.e. it's ok to just throw them in the toilet afterwards).  I usually take some of these along for hiking/camping trips when I'm not sure how long I'll have to go without a shower.

Comment: I like this idea. Wet toilet paper easily breaks down but I believe wet wipes can be carried easily in a purse or a bag.

Comment: Make sure you get the 'flushable' type. (horror stories https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=nl&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ad.nl%2Fad%2Fnl%2F1038%2FRotterdam%2Farticle%2Fdetail%2F2348844%2F2006%2F11%2F29%2FToiletdoekje-boosdoener-verstopping-rioolpijpen.dhtml&edit-text= )

Comment: is there a portable BIDET that you can i dont know attach to a bottle or something and then spray with the dry cleaning at the end

Answer (score 9):

Many of my Japanese colleagues (as well as Indian colleagues) usually prefer to stay in hotels that provide [bidet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidet) toilet pots. If that is not available then most will keep an empty bottle in their bathrooms. I can say this for sure about my buddies from the Middle East, India and Asia in general. It is fairly common to instruct house keeping not to dispose of the bottles from the bathroom. Or they will keep a glass which is washed regularly 
If one really needs to relieve themselves in a public bathroom, IMO, it is alright to take a PET bottle along with oneself. I have given away many of my used soda bottles to colleagues in *emergencies*. Even in public toilets I haven't seen anyone bat an eyelid if someone takes in a bottle of water with them. Just don't leave the place wet and soggy. If a bottle isn't available most people will simply wet some tissue paper at the sink and take it along with them as apparently cleaning with toilet paper will never give the *feeling* of clean to most people not used to it.

Comment: I really like the padded wet toilet paper idea. But I'm still wondering if there is a better solution to PET bottles.

Comment: I would like to combine yours' and Chris' answer. Is there some nifty way of doing something like this on SE? I feel your bidet suggestion is great and his wet wipes suggestion is great too!

Comment: I don't know how well the comment response system works. But I hope you're able to read my comment above. Would it be possible to do something like that?

Comment: @AdityaSomani Answers shouldn't be combined on SE.

Answer (score 4):

Get a Hand Bidet Sprayer, and then you can clean with water conveniently. Nothing you can do about a public toilet but as soon as you get home you'll be all set and your visiting guests will be much happier also!
[image]

Comment: Someone I know brought a plumbing 'T' joint and had this kinda sprayer/shower fixed in his bathroom. I think it barely costed USD 20 and the apartment maintenance guys installed this for free.

Comment: @user12649 I meant it as a reference to while travelling while using public toilets. We have those in almost every place in India. :D

Comment: I feel cold already if I think about using it in winter

Comment: Have it connected to a warm water pipe with a thermostat tap. (So you do not get HOT water down there.)

Comment: you should include a disclaimer that you are advertising for your own company

Comment: @forresthopkinsa spammers not really doing it, they spam and go. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I call it "Manual Bidet". Left hand with a rubber/plastic glove + water bottle. Use paper toilet paper to remove "excess" waste, then wash with water bottle. No direct handling of "poop". Believe me, I'm a male nurse...been cleaning patients for >40 years... :)

Answer (score 2):

There are Japanese products, which would do what you are looking for. You can find them in the online stores as "Portable Washlet" or "Washlet".

Answer (score 2):

OK, I am an Indian using Western toilets regularly and here is how I do it.

When you flush the toilet, water pours in from inside of the pot. I use my hands to direct that water to my anus, thereby cleaning it completely. However I find that toilet paper is always useful to administer the 'last rites', i.e., to remove all vestiges of faecal matter on the anus.

This is the default process I use in many places. However in some places a mug could be available, in which case, I pour tap water from the washbasin into the mug and use it.

The only concern in this method is regarding how you use your hands. Catch water while ensuring that hands do not touch the inside of the pot.

Answer (score -1):

Using tissue to clean the private parts not only makes some one feel unhygienic and dirty since it leaves residues and soils the clothes... Apart from this it also causes infections ... As the poop drops in the commode it splashes dirty water on the private parts from the commode below which normally doesn't happen in an Indian toilet.... Squatting while using an Indian toilet has its own advantages it prevents constipation and hemorrhoids/ piles to some extent which is proven scientifically... Western commodes are helpful in a few cases if you have elders at home who have joint problems... so install both in the houses... Americans have highest rate of UTI's in the world because they do not use water to wash their private parts during urinating or defecation...  The solution is simple carry a small bottle where ever you go .....  if not you will end up having urinary tract infections (UTI's)....  I am suggesting you this being a Doctor myself... Haha you can request the US government to install Indian toilets too along with western commodes...